# Clone sandbox with Encrypted fields

Tags: sandbox, encryption, platform-encryption

When a sandbox with encrypted fields is cloned to another sandbox, do those fields carry over encrypted, with all the same encryption settings? Or are they returned to a normal state when utilizing Platform Encryption? I am not finding any Salesforce documentation specifically outlining the answer to this question.  I found [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_sandboxes.htm&type=0), however it mentions production --> Sandbox.  Rather than Sandbox --> Sandbox

Comment: did you try this and see what would happen?  My suspicion is that the encryption WILL transfer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During any org copy procedure, metadata is always copied identically from the source org, with one exception: if the Org ID is used *anywhere*, it is automatically updated to the new org's ID value. This includes email template, reports, custom labels, formulas, validation rules, and so on. Encrypted fields would also remain encrypted, as that is part of the org's metadata.

Comment: Pretty much spot on with this answer.

Comment: The sandbox was copied and this is the behavior I saw.  Thanks @sfdcfox